# Where does Seahorse/GNOME keyring store its keyrings?

Tags: seahorse

I'm wondering where exactly Seahorse is storing the keyring data?

Most available information points to *~/.gnome2/keyrings/*, however, this directory contains only two very small files (*login.keyring*, 105 bytes and *user.keystore*, 207 bytes) which are definitely not large enough to contain the over 20 keys stored in my login keyring. I'd like to include the actual keyring data in my backup, so where is it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In Ubuntu 17.10, this is found under `~/.local/share/keyrings`

Comment: verified also on recent Fedora

Comment: Verified on recent Arch (Garuda Linux) as well

Comment: verified on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `~/.local/share/keyrings` in  Ubuntu 22.04 and Debian 11 (aka bullseye), `~/.gnome2/keyrings/` in Debian 10 (aka Buster).

Answer (score 7):

*sigh* ~/.gnome2/keyrings/ is the correct location after all, I was ssh'd to a different machine while checking and didn't notice... :-)

Comment: Just for others that come along - `~/.gnome2/keyrings/` was the old location for keyrings, this is now `~/.local/share/keyrings` in newer versions of gnome-keyring, seahorse, etc

Comment: Do note that gnome doesn't seem to move this directory even in new versions, so my fully upgrade gnome3 system was still happily using the `.gnome2` directory because that's what existed already.