# New Password for Default Keyring

Tags: xubuntu, chromium, gnome-keyring

Yesterday I was editing some videos on **Kdenlive**. It crashed and a prompt showed that I have very few disk space. Seeing this I analyzed the disk and found that **/tmp** folder was acquiring most of the space on the partion (*my linux partion is of around 42GB of which 19GB remains free*).
I inquired upon Google about **/tmp** folder and found that it is place where temporary files are stored and it is cleaned at every boot.

> > I may have delete some of those files manually.

Now at each boot, Ubuntu ask me for a new Default Keyring Password whenever I open **Chromium-Browser**, i.e. my Default Keyring Password resets on every boot.

I would also like to know why this happened. Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I didn't checked on Mozilla Firefox, but think that it would give same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I googled about the Default Keyring Application on Xubuntu and found out GNOME Keyring Manager daemon takes care of the password.

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96798/where-does-seahorse-gnome-keyring-store-its-keyrings), found where GNOME Keyring stores its files. Then deleted those files and it asked for password a last time and now it is back to normal. No more asking for setting up of new password at each boot.

Deleting files stored in given folder did the work for me.

```
~/.local/share/keyrings
```

P.S.: I only deleted files not any folder(*which weren't present there anyways.*)